# Implications of updating JHipster version

Tags: yeoman, jhipster, yeoman-generator

Ok, I want to start working with Angular2 and I'd like to do it through a JHipster generated application as this is the line of work we follow on some of our applications at work

I've been looking through a number of questions in SO such as:
[How to update the JHipster project after updating JHipster generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680663/how-to-update-the-jhipster-project-after-updating-jhipster-generator/30572331#30572331)
[How to upgrade jhipster sub-generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817394/how-to-upgrade-jhipster-sub-generator)

And I've also gone through the documentation of JHipster release 4.0.0 here: https://jhipster.github.io/2017/02/02/jhipster-release-4.0.0.html

But with all of that what still remains unclear to me are the implications that updating the subgenerator to the latest version would have on my existing applications

My concern is:

I do not wish to upgrade the already existing applications to the latest JHipster version nor to change from Angular 1 to 2 in them (at least not for a length of time) so in which way could updating the sub-generator affect my already existing applications when trying to work on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster (since version 3) installs itself into your project's local `node_modules` folder.  It should be included in your `package.json` under the dependencies section.

This means that when you run `yo jhipster` inside of your previously generated project folder, it loads the locally installed version specified in package.json instead of your globally installed version (which could be a different version).

You can verify the version your project uses by running `yo jhipster:info` or looking for the version in your `package.json`

Comment: Great answer! Thank you, so from this I understand two things: 1.- No implications what so ever to existing applications if I do not change the version in package.json  2.- If I do wish to update the applications, first step would be to update package.json and follow the steps on the SO items I included in my question

Comment: For point 2 you would use yo jhipster:upgrade see https://jhipster.github.io/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: Yes, you're right, on the SO threads they mention `yo jhipster` where it should be the upgrade tool, thank you for pointing that out @GaëlMarziou